# chef - replace coredump parameter in sysctl.conf file

Tags: chef-infra

for example am already having a parameter for the core dump i.e

kernel.core_pattern = /usr/local/core-%e.%t.%p.%u.%g

Now i wanted to change it to this i.e

kernel.core_pattern = /usr/local/core.%e.%p.%h.%t

mycode as follows :

```
ruby_block "edit /etc/sysctl.conf" do
    block do
        file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/sysctl.conf")
        file.search_file_replace_line(/^kernel.core_pattern.*$/, "kernel.core_pattern=/usr/local/core.%e.%p.%h.%t")
        rc.write_file
    end
    not_if "grep 'kernel.core_pattern' /etc/sysctl.conf"
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `FileEdit`, it's an internal API within Chef. In the general case, use the `line` or (disclaimer: mine) `poise-file` cookbooks if you must do in-place edits. That said, it is generally safer to manage whole files. In the case of sysctls specifically it does have to edit a file but we have a community cookbook ([`sysctl`](https://github.com/sous-chefs/sysctl)) that can handle the heavy lifting in this case.